# How to correctly use relationships with() in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, foreign-keys, relationship

I just wanted to clarify using the relationship in tables. Right now, I wanted to fetch records of `designation names` from `designation_id` in `employees` table.

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\{
    Designations,
    Positions
};

class Employees extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'employees';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = true;
    
    protected $casts = [
        'designation_id' => 'array',
        'position_id' => 'array',
        'basic_pay' => 'decimal:2',
    ];

    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'first_name', 
        'last_name',
        'designation_id',
        'position_id',
        'basic_pay',
    ];

    public function designations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Designations::class, 'id', 'designation_id');
    }

    public function positions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Positions::class, 'id', 'position_id');
    }
}
```

Here's my designation model:

```html
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Employees;

class Designations extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'designations';

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $timestamps = true;
    
    protected $dates = ['created_at', 'updated_at'];
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'description'
    ];

    public function employees()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employees::class, 'designation_id');
    }
}
```

Here's my `EmployeeController.php`:

```html
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\{
    Employees,
    Designations
};

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    { 
        $employees = Employees::with('designations', 'positions')->get();
        return array_reverse($employees);     
    }
}
```

I checked my api url, http://localhost:8000/api/employees and got this error:

`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: select * from` designations`where`designations`.`id `in (52))`

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships parameters are wrong. It's

```
hasMany(class, foreignKey, relatedPrimaryKey)
```

```
# Employee
public function designations()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Designations::class, 'employee_id', 'id');
}

public function positions()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Positions::class, 'employee_id', 'id');
}
```

If you're eager loading more than 1 relationship, use array notation.

Also, `$employees` will be an instance of a `Collection`, so you can't use it as an argument to `array_reverse`.

You can either use collection methods to achieve the same result, or use `$employees->all()` to get the underlying array.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Employees;

class EmployeesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    { 
        $employees = Employees::with(['designations', 'positions'])->get();

        return $employees->reverse()->values()->all();
        // OR
        return array_reverse($employees->all());
    }
}
```

---

This is assuming your tables have a structure like this:

```php
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    ...    
});

Schema::create('designations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('employee_id')->constained('employees');
    ...
});

Schema::create('positions', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignId('employee_id')->constained('employees');
    ...
});
```

Since you're using `increments` instead of `id()`, the code has to be a little different.

```php
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unique();
    ...    
});

Schema::create('designations', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unique();
    $table->unsignedInteger('employee_id');
    $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('employees');
    ...
});

Schema::create('positions', function (Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id')->unique();
    $table->unsignedInteger('employee_id');
    $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('employees');
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you guys. Right now, I corrected the relationships but got this error in api: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'designations.designation_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from designations` where designations.designation_id in (1))`

Comment: Is the foreign key really `designation_id` or is it something like `employee_id` in you rdesignations table? Can you post their structures?

Comment: Yes, foreign key is `designation_id`. For the employees table:  `Schema::create('employees',function(Blueprint $table){$table->increments('id')->unique();$table->string('first_name',50);$table->string('last_name',50);$table->json('designation_id');$table->json('position_id');$table->decimal('basic_pay');$table->timestamps();});`

Comment: Then for the designations table:  `Schema::create('designations',function(Blueprint $table){$table->id();$table->string('name');$table->longText('description')->nullable();$table->timestamps();});`

Comment: This is not a hasMany relationship. Using json columns for relationships is not generally suported either. If you want an **employee** to have many **designations** then the foreign key must be in the **designations** table (`$table->foreignId('employee_id')`)

Comment: I see. Okay, I'll try that one. Thanks IGP!

Comment: I've added some code for the minimal migrations expected for the relationships to work.

Comment: Should I remove `designation_id` and `position_id`: `Schema::create('employees',function(Blueprint $table){$table->id()->unique();$table->string('first_name',50);$table->string('last_name',50);$table->json('designation_id');$table->json('position_id');$table->unsignedInteger('incentive_id');$table->decimal('basic_pay');$table->timestamps()})`

Comment: I'm having this error with this, sorry: https://ibb.co/5n97b7f

Comment: Either add `nullable()` to `employee_id` in the migration or follow the instruction for instantiating factories that have relationships https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database-testing#belongs-to-relationships. `Position::factory()->count(3)->for(Employee::factory()->create())->create();`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to install phpstorm, it gives you hints of function parameters and you won't have this kind of issues anymore.

correct format is:

```html
return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

in your designations model:

```html
public function DesignationNames()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\Employees::class, 'designation_id', 'id');
    }
```

When you retrieve them in your controller you need to use the with() method as:

Designations::with('DesignationNames')->get();

And then to access properties in the related employee collection you would need to:

$designation->DesignationNames->DesignationProperty